# Stored procedure returning value in sql server but not in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net

I have a stored procedure which returns value (letterNo) without providing any parameter, it works but same procedure gives wrong value in asp.net code i.e. it returns only 0 but in SP it returns expected values like 1, 2 etc.

Why ?

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter]

 @LetterNo bigint output

AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Date varchar(5)
    Set @Date =(Select convert(Varchar(5),getdate(),110))

    Declare @MaxComposeLetterID bigint
    Set @MaxComposeLetterID = (Select MAX(ComposedLetterID) from ComposedLetter)

    Set @LetterNo= (Select Substring(ComposedLetter.LetterNo, 15,20) from ComposedLetter
    where ComposedLetterID= @MaxComposeLetterID)

    If (@Date !='01-01') --Check if it's first day of new year or not
    Begin
     Select @LetterNo + 1 as LetterNo  -- if not then it returns existing letterno + 1; incrementing old value
    End
    Else If(@Date= '01-01') -- if current date if 1st January then firstly it checks whether any other entry has been made or not, if made then existing value + 1
     Begin
      If(@LetterNo > 0) --if made then existing value + 1
         Begin
          Select @LetterNo + 1
         End
      Else
      Begin
       Set @LetterNo = 1  -- else if no new record has been inserted on 1st January then return intial value i.e. 1
       Select @LetterNo
      End
    End

END
```

.cs:
//Enclosed inside Page_Load Event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ManageComposedLetter mngCompLetters = new ManageComposedLetter();
            Int64 Letter_No = mngCompLetters.SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter();
            txtLetterNo.Text = "PPO-CC/" + DateTime.Now.Year + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/"+Letter_No;

}
```

Business Layer Code:

```
public Int64 SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter() 
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter", DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter pLetterNo = new SqlParameter("@LetterNo", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pLetterNo);
            pLetterNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Int64 Result = Convert.ToInt64(pLetterNo.Value);
            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: As you're selecting the number at the end of your proc, why not use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`? I think you may be confusing the output parameter with the result set.

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure returns multiple results.

```
Select @LetterNo + 1 as LetterNo  -- if not then it returns existing letterno + 1; incrementing old value
...
Select @LetterNo + 1
...
Select @LetterNo
```

You should either change them to

```
Select @LetterNo += 1 as LetterNo  -- if not then it returns existing letterno + 1; incrementing old value
...
Select @LetterNo += 1
...
Select @LetterNo = @LetterNo
```

or use the SET-operator

```
SET @LetterNo = @LetterNo + 1  
...
SET @LetterNo = @LetterNo + 1
...
SET @LetterNo = @LetterNo
```

The last assigment makes no sense (@LetterNo = @LetterNo) but it's taken from your code.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
pLetterNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
Int64 Result = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["@LetterNo"].Value);
```

**EDIT**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter]
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Date varchar(5)
Set @Date =(Select convert(Varchar(5),getdate(),110))

Declare @MaxComposeLetterID bigint
Set @MaxComposeLetterID = (Select MAX(ComposedLetterID) from ComposedLetter)

Declare @LetterNo bigint
Set @LetterNo= (Select Substring(ComposedLetter.LetterNo, 15,20) from ComposedLetter
where ComposedLetterID= @MaxComposeLetterID)

If (@Date !='01-01') --Check if it's first day of new year or not
Begin
 Select @LetterNo = @LetterNo + 1
 reutrn @LetterNo  -- if not then it returns existing letterno + 1; incrementing old value
End
Else If(@Date= '01-01') -- if current date if 1st January then firstly it checks whether any other entry has been made or not, if made then existing value + 1
 Begin
  If(@LetterNo > 0) --if made then existing value + 1
     Begin
      Select @LetterNo = @LetterNo + 1
      return @LetterNo
     End
  Else
  Begin
   Select @LetterNo = 1  -- else if no new record has been inserted on 1st January then return intial value i.e. 1
   return @LetterNo
  End
End
END
```

Where:

```
public Int64 SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter() 
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter", DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter pLetterNo = new SqlParameter("@LetterNo", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pLetterNo);
            pLetterNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Int64 Result = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["@LetterNo"].Value);
            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: not working, throwing error, 

 Procedure or function 'SelectLetterNoFromComposedLetter' expects parameter '@LetterNo', which was not supplied.

Comment: from what I can see of your stored procedure you are giving it a parameter `@LetterNo` and returning `@LetterNo` beneath the `select @LetterNo` lines add `return @LetterNo`

Comment: you may also have to add the `@LetterNo` parameter twice to your C# code.. e.g. `SqlParameter pLetterNo = new SqlParameter("@LetterNo", SqlDbType.BigInt);` and `SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("@LetterNo", SqlDbType.BigInt);`

Comment: @user1, you can edit your own answer, instead of putting several lines of code into comments.

Comment: See edit. Remove the output parameter and implement my edit. Should work then

Answer (score -1):

You could try set variable in statement's and on end of procedure select it.I think problem is there. I had similiar issue with EF.